# Why database isn't updating codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am currently working on this php app, which has a forum in it and I need a functionality of editing a certain topic.

My model:

```
public function update_topic(){

        $data = array(
            'topic_subject' => $this->input->post('topic_subject'),
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'topic_cat' => $this->input->post('topic_cat'),
            'topic_by' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')

        );

        $this->db->where('topic_id', $this->input->post('topic_id'));
        return $this->db->update('topics', $data);

    }
```

My controller:

```
    public function edit($topic_id){
    $data['topic'] = $this->topic_model->get_topics($topic_id);
    $data['forumcategories'] = $this->forumcategory_model->get_forumcategories();

    if(empty($data['topic'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Edit Topic';

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('forum/topics/edit', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function update(){

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect('users/login');
    }

    $this->topic_model->update_topic();

//  $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Post has been updated');
    redirect('forumcategories');
}
```

My form:

```
    <h2><?= $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>


<?php echo form_open('topics/update'); ?>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Topic Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="topic_subject" placeholder="Add Subject" value="<?php echo $topic['topic_subject']; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Body</label>
    <textarea id="editor" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add text"><?php echo $topic['body']; ?></textarea>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label>Category</label>
  <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
  <?php foreach($forumcategories as $forumcategory): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $forumcategory['cat_id']; ?>"> Name: <?php echo $forumcategory['cat_name']; ?> Description: <?php echo $forumcategory['cat_description']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

W
```

hen I click the edit button, the whole information loads perfectly, when I submit it does not throw any errors and it redirects me to the page i want to, but the info does not update, what could be the problem?

Comment: comment out `redirect('forumcategories');` and turn on `db_debug` in database.php. rerun and post error

Comment: commented the redirect and set the debugging value to true and it just sends me to a blank page and nothing else.

Comment: Okay after a few tries and messing around with the model, I found out that foreign keys were messing up, so I deleted them and one more problem was on edit form id of category select was wrong. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code goes into the controller for better practice, can you show us the form + debug like @Alex said or with an echo of the last query

```
 $dataa = array(
                'topic_subject' => $this->input->post('topic_subject'),
                'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
                'topic_cat' => $this->input->post('topic_cat'),
                'topic_by' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')

            );
```

then you call the model with $data

```
$this->topic_model->update_topic($dataa);
```

Comment: added my edit form,

Comment: Okay after a few tries and messing around with the model, I found out that foreign keys were messing up, so I deleted them and one more problem was on edit form id of category select was wrong. thank you for your help.